# Como validar campos do DBGrid antes de salvar?

Tags: delphi, validação, firebird, grid, delphi-xe2

Tenho um `DBGrid`, porém quero que ele valide os campos antes de salvar no banco de dados.

Eu acredito que tenha que utilizar o evento `BeforePost` porém não faço ideia de como fazer isso. Alguém poderia me dar uma dica?

Comment: Talvez isso possa ser feito no evento [`OnValidate`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE6/en/Data.DB.TField.OnValidate), ele ocorre antes que os dados sejam escritos. Que tipo de validação você queria fazer?

Comment: @Qmechanic73 eu quero apenas ver se todas as colunas estão preenchidas. Não conhecia esse evento, mas como faço para capturar esses dados antes de serem escritos?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fazer isso no evento [`TDataSet.BeforePost`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/Data.DB.TDataSet.BeforePost) não é má ideia, porém como você quer validar os *campos* em especifico, o evento [`DB.TField.OnValidate`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/Data.DB.TField.OnValidate) pode servir melhor para esse caso.

Para utilizar esse evento faça:

- Com o botão direito clique sobre o `AdoTable` (ou equivalente) e clique na primeira opção, *Fields Editor*.

  [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
- Na próxima janela selecione o campo que você quer fazer a validação.
- No *Object Inspector*, vá na aba *Events* e dê um duplo clique sobre `OnValidate`.

  [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agora basta você fazer a validação do campo, refaça o mesmo processo para os demais campos necessários. Assim quando o usuário editar tal campo, antes de ser salva a alteração, o `OnValidate` é chamado.

Por exemplo, se eu quero impedir que o usuário salve no campo *Animal* a palavra *girafa*, posso fazer:

```pascal
procedure TForm1.TblAnimaisAnimalValidate(Sender: TField);
begin
if Sender.AsString = 'girafa' then
   Abort;
end;
end;
```

Comment: Perfeito, mais uma vez muito obrigado. Funciona certinho.